# Dask fold with two data frames

Tags: python, data-science, dask, dask-delayed

This is a textbook question on how to add two DataFrames using Dask (specifically with fold)... I can't seem to get it to work though, so I wanted to reach out to see what I'm doing wrong.

(I'm on Python 3.8.5 with Dask 2021.4.1)

The code below shows my intentions:

```
from dask import delayed, bag
import pandas as pd

def get_df1():
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})

def get_df2():
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 2, 1], 'b': [6, 5, 4]})

def addit(a, b):
    return a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Without dask
    y = addit(get_df1(), get_df2())
    print(y)

    # The above code prints the desired answer:
    #    a   b
    # 0  4  10
    # 1  4  10
    # 2  4  10

    # With dask/delayed + bag + fold
    xs = [delayed(get_df1)(), delayed(get_df2)()]
    b1 = bag.from_delayed(xs)
    y = b1.fold(addit)
    print(y.compute())

    # This prints an unexpected result
    # abab
```

Answer (per comment below):

```
from dask import delayed, bag
import pandas as pd

def get_df1():
    return [pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})] # Now a list

def get_df2():
    return [pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 2, 1], 'b': [6, 5, 4]})] # Now a list

def addit(a, b):
    return a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Without dask
    y = addit(*get_df1(), *get_df2())
    print(y)

    # The above code prints the desired answer:
    #    a   b
    # 0  4  10
    # 1  4  10
    # 2  4  10

    # With dask/delayed + bag + fold
    xs = [delayed(get_df1)(), delayed(get_df2)()]
    b1 = bag.from_delayed(xs)
    y = b1.fold(addit)
    print(y.compute())

    # The above code now also prints the desired answer:
    #    a   b
    # 0  4  10
    # 1  4  10
    # 2  4  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises at this step:

```py
b1 = bag.from_delayed(xs)
```

What happens is `.from_delayed` expects each delayed to evaluate to a list, so you will need to modify your functions to return a list of dataframes:

```py
def get_df1():
    return [pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})]

def get_df2():
    return [pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 2, 1], 'b': [6, 5, 4]})]
```

After that your code should work.

Comment: Yes this worked and I've adjusted the code above per your comment.  Thank you!